# ActionResult from non-controller classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have decided that my controllers are getting a little to cluttered, and decided to adopt a pipeline-style system as I have used in a WebAPI project. The pipeline consists of actions, that get more and more general, i.e: `ViewAccountDetailsAction` > `AccountAction` > `AuthenticatedAction` > `EmptyAction`. The Actions both add to the pipleline in order of inheritance, and expose members, or abstract methods for different scenarios.

My problem lies in how to return views from pipeline elements. In the WebAPI example, it was as easy as returning an `IHttpActionResult` which didn't have to perform any view rendering, however, MVC is required to render its responses differently, with the additional step of Razor.

As Controllers expose `internal protected` helper methods like `View()` or `RedirectToAction`, I cant use these outside the controllers themselves.

Is there an elegant way to render these out? I have seen a few ways to do this, each being either cumbersome, or giving me uncomfortable feelings.

My most favoured way at the moment is to make an `internal` base class hiding the protected methods, and making them internal, whilst calling the base methods. The controller instance will then be provided to the instantiated action. Is there anything overly wrong with this? I can't think of any abusable cases, but wanted to see if there was any community consensus on the matter.

Comment: Side note: "MVC is required to render its responses differently, with the additional step of Razor" is somewhat  false statement as there is no requirements for action to even do anything (which can be easily confirmed by looking at `ActionResult.ExecuteResult`)... So you may be drawing incorrect conclusions out of your statement.

Comment: It sounds like you may be experiencing the "fat controller" anti-pattern. Read up on that and then maybe refactor the code into services that are called by a thin controller, using composition not inheritance to achieve the result.

Comment: I have put myself into a school of thought whereby controllers simply marshall RESTful/MVC routes to the respective operations they need to run. Maybe I need to reduce the scope of the `Action` to return a POCO or internal object then act accordingly, using some sort of signalling to generate the correct responses at the controller level. I don't know how well that will work as I would rather generate the views as soon as the results are known. I should also note that I am using Autofac to resolve dependancies, so I have a plethora of Request-scoped instances to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking your approach a step further.

This took a little bit of research, but I based it on an approach I did for a client with Web API 2. Basically the idea was we created a custom ControllerSelector, ActionSelector and ActionDescriptors and a controller base class that exposed a strongly typed business layer. Then through reflection/custom attributes, we marshalled the call to the business layer, handling transformations to an HttpResponseResponse message generically, including errors.

1. Controller: http://pastebin.com/iK8ieBKD
2. ControllerSelector: http://pastebin.com/qvEbggrP
3. ActionSelector: http://pastebin.com/CEFNeKZZ

The first thing you'll need to do is look at:
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/LYHK270114-Detailed-ASP.NET-MVC-Pipeline.html

Unfortunately ASP.NET MVC5's pipeline is much less flexible than Web API 2's. However you can do three things:

1. Custom Controller Factory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory(v=vs.118).aspx
2. Custom ControllerDescriptor
3. Custom ActionInvoker that interprets the ControllerDescriptor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactioninvoker(v=vs.118).aspx

This way you leave your controller to do what controllers do best, and create a contract for your controller to generically interpret using your new pipeline. This is really the right way to do it.

High jacking/bastardizing the controller as you suggested I don't think is a great plan, this is a much more robust solution, however it would take significant effort. Best of luck!

Comment: Note: the route prioritization logic is pretty garbage, I refactored that at some point so it would just interpret the Route string (no need for prioritization array), at some point that change got reversed.